# condicion de un if con select

Tags: sql, postgresql, bucle-for, condiciones

Solicito su colaboración, tengo una serie de tablas llamada `rutaN` (donde N va de 1 a 3782), que tiene información de rutas con diferentes aerolíneas.

Debo entrar a evaluar si la aerolínea de la primera ruta es diferente a la aerolínea de la siguiente ruta, si es así se debe incrementar en un **10%**. Tengo el siguiente código, pero me calcula el **10%** así no cumpla con la condición. Aclaro que el **`i`** es porque esta dentro de un ciclo **`for`**.
Tengo este código dentro de un `for loop` pero no me reconoce la condición

```
do
$do$
declare
     i int;
begin
for  i in 1..3782
loop
-- Se crea la ruta con el algoritmo de dijkstra
    execute
    'create temporary table pasos_ruta' ||i|| '(seq int, path_seq int, node int, edge bigint, cost float, agg_cost float)';

    execute
    'insert into pasos_ruta' ||i|| '(seq, path_seq, node, edge, cost, agg_cost)
        select * from pgr_dijkstra (''select *, id, distancia as cost from aerolineas'', 
                                (select orig_id from rutas_posibles where id_ruta ='||i||'),
                                (select dest_id from rutas_posibles where id_ruta ='||i||'),
                                false);';

    execute
    'create temporary table ruta' ||i|| '(cod_ruta bigint, id bigint, origen varchar(30), destino varchar(30), aerolinea varchar(30), precio_base int, distancia float, orig_geom geometry(point,3116), dest_geom geometry(point,3116), ruta_geom geometry, source int, target int, dist_total float, precio_tramo float, precio_ruta float, seq int)';

    execute
    'insert into ruta' ||i|| '(id, origen, destino, aerolinea, precio_base, distancia, orig_geom, dest_geom, ruta_geom, source, target, seq)
    select id, origen, destino, aerolinea, precio_base, distancia, orig_geom, dest_geom, ruta_geom, source, target, seq from aerolineas v natural join
    (select edge id, * from pasos_ruta'||i||') r
    where r.id=v.id';

if ('select aerolinea from ruta'||i||' where seq=1')<>('select aerolinea from ruta'||i||' where seq=3') then
    
        execute
        'update ruta'||i||' set precio_base=((150*.10)+150)
        where seq=3';
    end if;
end loop;
end;
$do$;
```

Tengo este como ejemplo y si funciona:

```
create temporary table rutapr1 as
        select * from pgr_dijkstra ('select *, id, distancia as cost from aerolineas', 
                                (select orig_id from rutas_posibles where id_ruta ='3781'),
                                (select dest_id from rutas_posibles where id_ruta ='3781'),
                                false);
    

create table camino_pr1 as
select * from aerolineas v natural join
(select edge id, * from rutapr1) r
where r.id=v.id

do
$do$
declare
begin

    if (select aerolinea from camino_pr1 where seq=1)<>(select aerolinea from camino_pr1 where seq=3) then

        update camino_pr1 set precio_base=((150*.10)+150)
        where seq=3;
    end if;

end;
$do$
```

Aclaro que el ejemplo es la tabla 'ruta3781', debo crear 3782 tablas por lo cual el código lo tengo dentro de un `for`, así que el homónimo de `ruta3781` seria `'ruta'||i||`. Creo que en lo que estoy fallando es en la sintaxis del código al ponerle el `||i||` no reconoce la condición del `if`.

Dentro del `for` se crea una tabla por cada ruta, ejemplo:
`ruta1`, `ruta2`, `ruta3`, y así sucesivamente hasta `ruta3782`.

El ejemplo que agregue es un ejemplo de una tabla llamada `ruta3781`, pero necesito que funcione dentro del for para que cree las `3782` tablas, por lo cual se crea la tabla `ruta||i||` dentro del for.

Trabajo en Postgres 9.6 con pgadmin III 1.22

Comment: Con qué motor de base de datos trabajas?

Comment: El `i` que se ve en el código no tiene ningún efecto dentro de un ciclo, pues está puesto como un alias de la tabla `ruta`; literalmente la letra `i`, sin importar si hay una variable con ese nombre y cual sea su valor.

Comment: Por favor especifica las herramientas con las que estás trabajando. Para que sea más fácil ayudarte

Comment: Tambien le falta cerrar las comillas antes del 'end if'

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tene en cuenta que, no sabemos con que motor trabajas.. no sabemos donde escribiste ee codigo. no se entiende que tratas de hacer. el codigo tiene errores de sintaxis. Por favor, ajusta todos esos problemas para que podamos entender mejor tu problema.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en postgres 9.6, utilizando pgadmin

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que se ve en los ejemplos que pones, no tienes una tabla llamada `rutas`, como afirmas en tu pregunta. Queda claro que tienes una tabla llamada `ruta3781`, y probablemente cientos o miles de tablas llamadas `rutaN`. Creo que convendría todavía que aclarases bien ese punto, y que incluyeras, al menos, un esbozo del ciclo que estás ejecutando, para ver si así logras ponernos en contexto de la situación.

Comment: Otra cosa que observo es que el ejemplo que muestras (el que si funciona) usa un campo llamado `seq` mientras que el que no funciona utiliza un campo llamado `num`.

Comment: Creo que ahora si queda claro, ya nominé la pregunta para su re-apertura, esperemos que la comunidad reaccione positivamente, a ver si @gbianchi nos echa una mano también. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Ahora la re abrimos... pero por favor aclara si realmente tenes una tabla por ruta. Si es asi, ahi radica tu principal problema y eso es lo que tenemos que arreglar

Comment: Viéndo el código y leyendo el texto de la pregunta, ahora queda claro que hay más de 3000 tablas (temporales) que se llaman `ruta1`, `ruta2`... `ruta3782`.

Comment: porque hay mas de 3000 tablas??? eso nu suena para nada correcto en ningun caso!... podrias explicar eso.. tal vez tus problemas empiezan por ahi...

Comment: Es una mala estrategia la de tener 3000 tablas, cuando una sola tabla podría servir. Te sugiero revisar el modelo de datos y consolidar la información en una sola tabla, con una columna adicional `id_ruta` que identifique las filas de cada ruta..

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no te has dado cuenta, pero lo que en realidad estás haciendo es ejecutando [SQL dinámico](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/ecpg-dynamic.html), invocando a `execute`.

Este se llama así, porque lo que haces es construir sentencias SQL válidas dentro de cadenas de caracteres y luego le solicitas al motor que las ejecute.

Por ejemplo, la sentencia:

```
execute
    'insert into ruta' ||i|| '(id, origen, destino, aerolinea, precio_base, distancia, orig_geom, dest_geom, ruta_geom, source, target, seq)
    select id, origen, destino, aerolinea, precio_base, distancia, orig_geom, dest_geom, ruta_geom, source, target, seq from aerolineas v natural join
    (select edge id, * from pasos_ruta'||i||') r
    where r.id=v.id';
```

Va concatenando el valor de tu variable de control `i`, para generar sentencias `insert` a distintas tablas, cuando `i` vale `1`, hará un `insert into ruta1`, cuando `i` vale 752, hará un `insert into ruta752`, etc.

Si comparas eso con tu sentencia `if`, notarás que en realidad estás comparando dos cadenas de caracteres (que contienen sentencias SQL, si, pero que nunca son ejecutadas).

```
if ('select aerolinea from ruta'||i||' where seq=1')<>('select aerolinea from ruta'||i||' where seq=3') then
```

Sería más o menos equivalente a hacer esto (he quitado todo lo que hace que parezca que hay SQL de por medio y he dejado lo que hace que las cadenas sean distintas:

```
if ('ruta'||i||'1')<>('ruta'||i||'3') then
```

Y las cadenas son distintas siempre, por lo tanto, siempre entrará a ejecutar lo que tienes dentro del `if`.

Dicho esto, he de decir que no soy usuario habitual de postgresql y no lo tengo a mano para hacer una prueba, así que de aquí en adelante hablaré en base a mis expectativas y te daré alternativas.

Si el SQL dinámico de postgresql soporta ejecutar sentencias `if` (cosa que no encontré en una búsqueda en la documentación), podrías generar una cadena que contenga todo el `if` completo y mandar a ejecutarla:

Eso, tomando en cuenta tu ejemplo de lo que si funciona, sería algo como:

```
execute
'if (select aerolinea from ruta'||i||' where seq=1)<>(select aerolinea from ruta'||i||' where seq=3) then

        update ruta'||i||' set precio_base=((150*.10)+150)
        where seq=3;
    end if;'
```

Es probable que para que esto se ejecute correctamente tengas que convertirlo en un bloque completo (incluyendo la sentencia `do` dentro de la cadena, te dejo a ti hacer la prueba si no te funciona a la primera.

Dado que cabe la posibilidad que el motor no soporte ejecutar un if ni dentro de un bloque `do`, otra opción es sustituir completamente el if por una única sentencia `update` que haga la actualización solo bajo las condiciones adecuadas.

Para mi, esta sentencia sería algo como

```
update ruta1742 
   set precio_base = 165
 where seq=3
   and aerolinea <> (select b.aerolinea
                       from ruta1742 b
                      where b.seq = 1)
```

He quitado la fórmula para calcular el nuevo precio_base, ya que al ser todos los valores constantes, me parece que no es necesaria, pero puedes regresarla.

La actualización sucederá solamente si la aerolínea de `seq = 1` es distinta de la aerolínea de `seq = 3`, que es lo que buscas.

Ya te dejo a ti el ejercicio de meter esto en una cadena, concatenando la `i` donde haga falta y lanzarla con `execute`.